# Shared Access Signature to manipulate Azure blob container

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I would like to give SAS uris to other applications to allow them to send files to a blob container. However the code fails when trying to upload a file giving me an exception which states:

> Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

I'm using aspnetcore and WindowsAzure.Storage version 9.1.0.

```
        var acc = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("mysecrets");
        CloudBlobClient client = acc.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = client.GetContainerReference("myblobcontainer");
        await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
        var permissions = container.GetPermissionsAsync().Result;
        permissions.SharedAccessPolicies.Add("writepolicy",
            new SharedAccessBlobPolicy
            {
                Permissions =
                    SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Add |
                    SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Create |
                    SharedAccessBlobPermissions.List |
                    SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write,
            });
        await container.SetPermissionsAsync(permissions);
        var sas = container.GetSharedAccessSignature(null, "writepolicy");
        var accessUri = container.Uri.ToString() + sas;

        var cloudBlobContainer = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri(accessUri));
        var blob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("myfile.txt");
        await blob.UploadFromFileAsync("foo.txt");
```

I have also tried creating the cloudBlobContainer like this:

```
var cloudBlobContainer = 
             new CloudBlobContainer(container.Uri, new StorageCredentials(sas));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially the problem is that your `Shared Access Signature (SAS)` is missing `Expiry Date` i.e. date/time when the SAS will expire.

When I ran your code, I got the same error. But when I traced the request/response through Fiddler, this is what Storage Service had sent back:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Error>
    <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
    <Message>
      Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
      RequestId:320035be-801e-0040-6e5e-c30407000000
      Time:2018-03-24T10:57:38.7791868Z
    </Message>
    <AuthenticationErrorDetail>
      Signed expiry must be specified in signature or SAS identifier
    </AuthenticationErrorDetail>
  </Error>
```

What you need to do is add the expiry date/time. You could either add to the shared access policy or specify this when you're creating SAS (but not at both places).

Please use the following code to create SAS:

```
    var policy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
    {
        SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15)
    };
    var sas = container.GetSharedAccessSignature(policy, "writepolicy");
```

Comment: Thank you, this was driving me crazy. Had not thought of running fiddler to view the request.

Comment: Fiddler is your best friend in all cases :). You get so much information about the operation right away and is especially very useful when Storage SDK does not expose error details directly (you have to dig deep in the SDK to find this information).